# What is the good practice for typescript objects from apis in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

What is the good practice for instanciate objects from api calls ?

I am using Angular / NestJS frameworks and when an object is returned from the api it is as a json response (in my case) and when I wrap it in and object like :

```
this.objectService.findOne(this.objectId).subscribe(
        (response: Object) => {
            this.myObject = response;
        }
    );
```

I will not be able to use functions of my object because it is not instantiated (I assume that the type Object in the reponse I something like a mask). If this is well known issue, I feel a need to know what is the best thing to do to have instantiated objects from api returns taking account that it will occurs in many places in my app.

Maybe these hypothesis are wrong :

- Never declaring functions in the objects classes of api returns, use otherwise helpers or other
- Copy the same keys from api response to a new Object (in constructor ?) like :

  ```
  this.myObject = new Object(response);
  ```
- Make the api service directly instanciate the object from response
- Do whatever I want there are no best practice in this case...

Comment: The part `Never declaring functions` is important. In OO design, such objects are known as DTO (data transfer object) and they are not supposed to have fancy methods declared on them except maybe binding functions that convert the DTO to your model objects and in other languages serializing functions to convert such objects to and from JSON/XML etc (in js/ts we normally use JSON.parse and JSON.stringify). See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object

Comment: Thank you for this precision. So I would declare a DTO and a class apart for business logic. So the Serialize / Deserialize would be in the class or in the DTO (static though) ?

Comment: For other languages (eg Java) the serialization method is sometimes implemented in the DTO thought this practice is slowly disappearing in favor of external serialization library (eg. Jackson in Java). For js I'd strongly recommend you don't implement serialization in the DTO itself. The whole point of a DTO is that it is a plain object so you can pass it to external libraries or functions such as `JSON.stringify()` and get correct protocol format to send over the network